# Movie about an invasion of shapeshifting aliens, a college boy dates one in the shape of a model

Tags: story-identification, movie, alien-invasion, shape-shifter

I saw this on VHS when I was a kid. It's a '70s-'80s film about shapeshifting, sea cockroach-looking aliens that were invading earth. The plot centered around a high school senior/college boy who had a crush on this cover girl, and one of these aliens stuck itself to one of her posters and transformed into her. I believe they dated and then maybe, just maybe the girl alien helped him survive? Or beat the other aliens? Or did she turn on him too?

I remember the main character took her out on a date to one of his schoolmate's house parties, and everyone was jealous of him. It was a proud moment for the young lad, for some time anyway.

Comment: Sounds a bit like _The Faculty (1998)_, but I'm guessing that's not it.

Comment: Also a bit like [Crittes 2](https://youtu.be/iZnRbhCDEv8?t=57) =)

Comment: @guru - Would you say this was a family movie, or more a horror?

Comment: @LogicDictates I can't say... I do remember the green color palette used most often.. like ye olde green light coming from space ships or something. It's that typical highschool kid who got to date a hot girl kinda movie. 

And no, it's not The Faculty, although that's one I'm downloading soon for some classic binge moments.

Yaroslav, yeah, I don't think the mc woul wanna date a critter. :P

Answer (score -2):

Could this be MEET THE APPLEGATES?
[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet_the_Applegates?wprov=sfti1)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to explain why you think this might be the correct movie, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. It'd help the rest of us to decide how likely this answer is to be correct, and whether we should therefore upvote it or not.

Comment: I fail to see how this is much of a match